# Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int Generator

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2015, header, name-lookup

I have a problem with the following code:

### `Generator.h:`

```
#pragma once
class Generator
{
public:
    friend class BagObject; 
    Generator(void);
    ~Generator(void);
    ...
    void generator(int);
private:
    BagObject *object;
    vector<BagObject> data; //Error c4430
};
```

And this is the error:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

(There are 6 more errors but I believe that they should disappear after solving the above problem.)

### `Generator.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Generator.h"
#include "BagObject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

Generator::Generator(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
}

Generator::~Generator(void)
{
    data.clear();
}

void Generator::generator(int ld)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<ld; i++)
{
    object = new BagObject(rand(),rand(),i);
    data.push_back(object);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Generator *g = new Generator;
    g->generator(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am just guessing but didnt you forget `std::vector` or include the BagObject header?

Answer (score 16):

Either you forgot to include header

```
#include <vector>
```

or forgot to write directive

```
using namespace std;
```

In any case it would be better to write

```
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<BagObject> data;
^^^^^
```

You have to include the header `<vector>` in all headers where there is a reference to `std::vector`.

Comment: Looking at `#pragma once` statement you dont want to recommend `using namespace std` as this is most probably a header file

Comment: @AdrianLis Where do you have  seen that I recommend to use it?

Comment: maybe recommend wasnt the best choice of words but you did suggest maybe he forgot to write `using namespace std`, and doing so isn't a good option in this case because of the header.

Comment: @AdrianLis I see that he uses unqualified names so I concluded that he already uses the directive.

Comment: Whatever you did or did not recommend, I recommend *not* writing `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: @KeithThompson The question is not about using or not using the directive. The question is about why the compiler error occurred. And moreover he is a beginner and maybe learn the language by reading some book where all examples have this directive. So when someone will ask a question about this directive you can give your advice.:)

Comment: Thank you for your input. If I were answering the question, I would have posted an answer. I posted a comment, in response to other comments. If you don't want me giving my advice, I'm afraid that's just too bad.

Comment: When i Write `std::vector<BagObject> data;` i got one more error `Error C2039 'vector': is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: @HeHacz As I wrote in my answer you have to include header vector like #include <vector>. The class vector is declared in this header.

Comment: I include `#include <vector>` and `#include "BagObject.h"` still same error.

Comment: @HeHacz If you included <vector> then this error can not occur. It means that you included the header in some other compilation unit instead of this one.

Comment: @HeHacz: Your header file `Generator.h` refers to `vector`. Do you have `#include <vector>` *in `Generator.h`*? (In addition to that, you'll need to *either* refer to `std::vector` rather than just `vector` *or* add `using namespace std;`.)

Comment: @HeHacz Check all headers where there is a reference to std::vector and include there the header.

Comment: Ok i create a simple program that use vector and there is a problem with my dll files so i need probably to reinstal  C++ redistributable.

Comment: @HeHacz Maybe. We know nothing about your dll.:)

Answer (score 10):

Other answers are correct, but cryptic. In plain English, your header does not know about `BagObject` class. You included `BagObject.h` in the `.cpp`, but you should have included it in the `.h`.

It also does not know about `vector` for the same reason.

I am guessing, you were under impression that `.cpp` had to use `#include`, but `.h` did not. This is a common misunderstanding of beginners in C++. Headers need to include all referenced class declarations, hence you need to elevate your includes from `.cpp` into your `.h`.

Move two mentioned includes into the header and it will work.

Comment: Sir, thank you from the bottom of my heart, you solved a problem that no one in the Unreal Engine community was able to resolve decently..
Someone was saying "You can't forward declare enums", someone else "You can't use that macro", I was able to do both just including the file where the enum was declared in the .h file (In unreal almost everything is included in the .cpp)

Answer (score 3):

`vector` may not be instantiated with an incomplete type. In order to have `vector<BagObject> data;` in the header, the header must also have `#include "BagObject.h"`.

(This is in addition to the changes recommended in Vlad's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I know your problem is solved but in My case the same error was caused due to cyclic includes (i.e. I had accidentally included the .h file in one of the .h file included in it)

TextureManager.h  (The file with the error)

```
// This is TextureManager.h
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

/*
 texture manager class
*/
```

GameObject.h

```
// This is GameObject.h
#pragma once
#include "game.h"
#include "TexutureManager.h" // Accidental
/*

*/
```

I thought it may be worth noting this is also one of the ways to get this error.